# Can't use jquery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to use jquery tablesorter.

Different tutorials describe in different way how to do it, but I am not able to display this table. This is my first project with jquery and after viewing this library i recognize that tablesorter is not default function of jquery.

This is what I've done. 
1. Download jquery.tablesorter.min.js using nuget
2. Add extra line to BundleConfig.cs to include tablesorter;

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery.tablesorter").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.pager*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
```

3. Modify _Layout.cshtml

   ```
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
   @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery.tablesorter")
   ```
4. Modify Index.cshtml

   ```
   @section scripts
   {
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery.tablesorter")
       <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function () {
           $(".tablesorter").tablesorter();
           $("#jumbotron").css({ "border": "1px solid black" });
           $("table").tablesorter();
       });

       </script>
    }

    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
           <tr>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Salary</th> 
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>Rambo</td>
               <td>John</td>
               <td>jrambo@gmail.com</td>
               <td>$150.00</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>Abc</td>
               <td>def</td>
               <td>abcdef@yahoo.com</td>
               <td>$150.00</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>qwe</td>
               <td>rty</td>
               <td>qwerty@gmail.com</td>
               <td>$110.00</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>qaz</td>
               <td>wsx</td>
               <td>qazwsx@gmail</td>
               <td>$150.00</td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
   ```

I am able to change css style of that table using jquery but not able to use tablesorter. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it working on jsfiddle with this line of code:

`$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#myTable").tablesorter();
}`

https://jsfiddle.net/rxc14nLs/3/

Also, I noticed that you have not included the css file for the table in your bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "PATH_TO_TABLESORTER_CSS_THEME_HERE", 
              "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Comment: Thank You. I added css file to project and in BundleConfig.cs add extra line of code to include this file. I was thinking that tablesorter have included css styles.